# Help me to remove subscriber from mass mail php script

Tags: php, massmail, subscriber

i need to find a way to remove subscribers from mass mail php script
here is script:

```
<?php

$thisfile=basename(__FILE__, ".php");

$path = GSPLUGINPATH.'gs_massmail/lang/';
$filenames = getFiles($path);
foreach ($filenames as $file) {
 if($file == $LANG.'.php')
  $language_file = $file;
}

if($language_file == FALSE)
 $language_file = 'en_US.php';

require_once $path.$language_file;

add_action('plugins-sidebar','createSideMenu',array($thisfile, 'Mass Mail'));

function get_mass_mail_form(){
 global $i18n;
?>
 <form action="<?php get_page_url(); ?>" method="post" class="contactform" >
  <?php set_mass_mail_page(); ?>
  <p>
   <input type="text" class="text" name="massmail[email]" value="e-mail" onFocus="doClear(this)" onBlur="doDefault(this)" />
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit" class="submit" value="<?php echo $i18n['MM_SUBSCRIBE']?>" id="add-receiver" name="add-receiver" /></p>
 </form> 
<?php
}

function show_editor(){
 global $i18n, $HTMLEDITOR;
 ?>
  <h3><?php echo $i18n['MM_SENDMAIL']?></h3>
  <form method="post" class="sendmassmail">
   <p>
    <b><?php echo $i18n['MM_SUBJECT']?></b>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" size="70"/>
   </p>
   <p>
    <textarea id="post-content" rel="<?php echo $i18n['LABEL_PAGEBODY']; ?>" name="post-content"></textarea>
   </p> 
   <p><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submitted" value="<?php echo $i18n['MM_SENDMAILTOALL']?>" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $i18n['OR']; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp; <a class="cancel" href="pages.php?cancel"><?php echo $i18n['CANCEL']; ?></a></p>
  </form>

  <?php 
   if (defined('GSEDITORHEIGHT')) { $EDHEIGHT = GSEDITORHEIGHT .'px'; } else { $EDHEIGHT = '500px'; }
   if (defined('GSEDITORLANG')) { $EDLANG = GSEDITORLANG; } else { $EDLANG = 'en'; }
   if (defined('GSEDITORTOOL')) { $EDTOOL = GSEDITORTOOL; } else { $EDTOOL = 'basic'; }


   if ($EDTOOL == 'advanced') {
    $toolbar = "
      ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock', 'Table', 'TextColor', 'BGColor', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Image', 'RemoveFormat', 'Source'],
           '/',
           ['Styles','Format','Font','FontSize']
       ";
   } else {
    $toolbar = "['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Image', 'RemoveFormat', 'Source']";
   }
  ?>
  <?php if ($HTMLEDITOR != '') { ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="template/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('post-content', {
          skin : 'getsimple',
          forcePasteAsPlainText : true,
          language : '<?php echo $EDLANG; ?>',
          defaultLanguage : '<?php echo $EDLANG; ?>',
          entities : true,
          uiColor : '#FFFFFF',
    height: '<?php echo $EDHEIGHT; ?>', 
          toolbar : 
          [
          <?php echo $toolbar; ?>
    ]
          //filebrowserBrowseUrl : '/browser/browse.php',
          //filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '/browser/browse.php?type=Images',
          //filebrowserWindowWidth : '640',
          //filebrowserWindowHeight : '480'
      });
  </script>
  <?php 
  }
}


function setup_mass_mail(){
  global $emailadresses;
  global $_POST, $i, $b, $i18n;

  $xmlfile = GSDATAPATH."other/massmail.xml";
  set_mass_mail_css();
  $v = getXML($xmlfile);

  if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
   if(strlen($_POST['subject']) == 0 || strlen($_POST['post-content']) == 0)
    $err[] = $i18n['MM_SUBJECTANDMESSAGE'];

   if(count($err) == 0){
    echo "<h3>".$i18n['MM_EMAILSTATUS']."</h3>";
    $server_name = getenv ("SERVER_NAME");       // Server Name
    $request_uri = getenv ("REQUEST_URI");       // Requested URI

    $from = 'noreply@'.substr($server_name, 4, strlen($server_name));

    if(isset($_POST['subject']))
     $subject = $_POST['subject']; //htmlentities($_POST['subject'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    else
     $subject = $i18n['MM_NEWSLETTERFROM'].$server_name;

    $headers = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: ".$from."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
     $body = stripslashes($_POST['post-content']); //htmlentities($_POST['post-content'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    else
     $body = $_POST['post-content'];

    foreach ($v as $row => $value) {
     if(mail($value->email,$subject,$body,$headers))
      $i++;
     else
      $b++;
    }   
    echo '<p class="ok">'.$i18n['MM_MAILWASSENTTO'].' ('.$i.' '.$i18n['MM_OF'].' '.($b+$i).')<p>';
   } else {
    echo '<p class="error">'.implode(".<br />", $err).'</p>';
   }
  }
  echo "<h3>".$i18n['MM_SUBSCRIBERS']."</h3>";
  if(file_exists($xmlfile) ) { 
   echo '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <tr>
      <td>
      '.$i18n['MM_DATE'].'
      </td>
      <td>
      '.$i18n['MM_EMAIL'].'
      </td>
     </tr>
   ';
   foreach ($v as $row => $value) {
    $emailadresses .= $value->email.';';
    echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>'.date('Y-m-d', (int)$value->date).'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$value->email.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
   }
   echo '</table>';
   echo '<p><b>'.$i18n['MM_COMMASEPARATED'].':</b> <br />'.$emailadresses;
   show_editor();
  } else {
   echo $i18n['MM_NOREGSUBSCRIBERS'];
  }
}

function set_mass_mail_css(){
 echo '
 <!-- CSS for Mass Mail plugin -->
 <style type="text/css">
  p.ok {
   color: #3dc32b;
  }
  p.error {
   color: #FF0000;
  }
 </style>';
}

function set_mass_mail_page(){
 global $email;
 global $i18n;
 if (isset($_POST['add-receiver'])) {
  set_mass_mail_css();
  $xmlfile = GSDATAPATH."other/massmail.xml";
  $email = $_POST['massmail']['email'];
  $err = array();

  if(!check_email_address($_POST['massmail']['email'])){
   $err[] = $i18n['MM_EMAILWRONGFORMAT'];
  } else {
   if(file_exists($xmlfile) ) { 
    $v = getXML($xmlfile);
    foreach ($v as $row) {
     if($row->email == $_POST['massmail']['email']){
      $err[] = $i18n['MM_EMAILALLREADYREG'];
      break;
     }
    }
   }    
  }

  if(count($err) == 0){
   if (!file_exists($xmlfile) ) { 
    $xml = @new SimpleXMLExtended('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><item></item>');
   } else {   
    $xmldata = file_get_contents($xmlfile);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLExtended($xmldata);
   }
   $thislog = $xml->addChild('entry');
   $thislog->addChild('date', time());
   $thislog->addChild('email', $email);
   $xml->asXML($xmlfile);
   echo '<p class="ok">'.$i18n['MM_YOUARENOWSUBSCRIBER'].'</p>';
  } else {
   echo '<p class="error">'.implode(".<br />", $err).'</p>';
  }
 }
}

?>
```

thanks

Comment: I think you should specify what you want us to help you with. We're not going to write code for you or figure out what the bug is in a long piece of code if you don't bother to narrow it down. Tell us what you've tried so far, and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Holy moly.

You should be able to edit the other/massmail.xml file that this creates via Notepad or any other text editor.

If you wish to edit it programmitcally (not really word), I believe you can loop through each XML node using the SimpleXMLExtended class (as shown in your code). If possible, you should consider reading it node by node so the whole file isn't loaded into memory.

As a side note: I strongly recommend not using XML for storing a mailing list. It'd be much easier and more efficient to manage if you used a database such as MySQL (or SQLite if you insist on storing it in a file).